# What happens when Ryo spends all his money before trying to buy the ticket?

Tags: shenmue

On Disc 2 of Shenmue, Ryo tries to get a ticket to Hong Kong.

Because Ryo has not enough money, Fuku-san gives his piggy bank savings to Ryo. Ryo is now able to buy a boat ticket (¥69000) at the Asia Travel Company.

**What happens if Ryo spends all his money (including Fuku-san’s savings) for toy capsules *before* buying this ticket?**

Would you have to earn it back the hard way before the story can progress?

- I guess working at the harbor isn’t possible yet (or is it?).
- Ine-san gives you ¥500 each day. It would take 138 days. Not possible, because you’d be [game over](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/131858/30863) beforehand.
- Slot machines. As far as I read, you can’t make money here (you can only get tokens and items).

Any other ways to earn money at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot spend the money before you buy the ticket - the game stops you from doing so.

In this Let's Play video, you can see an attempt to buy Squid Legs is made but the game prevents it: "I have to buy the ticket first"

[Let's Play Shenmue, part 33 (minute 11)](http://youtu.be/cuOX426q0DI?t=11m20s)