# Alternative ending in Shenmue?

Tags: shenmue

I heard there is an alternative ending in **Shenmue I**.

What is it and how do you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game starts on 1986-11-29. If you don’t finish the game before **1987-04-15**, you’ll see the "bad ending" and you are game over.

You can see the cutscene here:

---

There is a quick way to reach this date:

On Disc 2, when trying to sneak into the Old Warehouse district, there is a QTE at the entrace where you have to catch the flashlight. If you fail here, a day is skipped and you can try again immediately (this happens automatically, so you could put down your controller and come back later).

You can see a speedrun (1:50:59) here: