# Is there a bad ending in Shenmue II?

Tags: shenmue-2

In *Shenmue*, there’s a [bad ending](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131859/30863) if you don’t finish the game before a certain date.

The booklet of *Shenmue II* (from the Dreamcast PAL version, page 26) says:

> **Overall Time Limit**
>
> Time will pass, even when you are not doing anything.
>   The game starts on a cold winter’s day.
>
> There is no need to rush your way through the game, take your time and admire the scenery if you wish, however, you are expected to reach your goal before the summer comes around.
>
> Enjoy the world of "Shenmue II" …

So I’m "expected to reach [my] goal before the summer comes around". But what happens if I take longer than that? **Is there also a bad ending in *Shenmue II*?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, *Shenmue II* also has a bad ending.

It triggers if you go to bed on **1987-06-31**.

You can see [the cutscene that follows here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fseoytKGmFk):

(It’s also [available with the English dub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXt8FeMM8Y8).)

---

A quick way to reach this date is the QTE in Zhangyu Barber’s Shop. If you [fail it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQf3R8RiFwU), a whole day passes.